# Which R package has basic map data of Europe embedded?

Tags: r

Where can I find open source map data for countries in Europe? 
I need geographical data such as borders, rivers,elevation 
and I need also statistical data (population, etc.)

Is there by chance an R package available, what would provide me basic data of european countries, which I could extract countrywise?

Comment: Are you referring to actual files (*e.g.* shapefiles) or basemaps such as the one open street map provides?

Comment: I am referring to both: I checked data in the OSM package with data( package="OpenStreetMap"):Data sets in package ‘OpenStreetMap’:

1. LA_places            Places of interest in Los Angeles
2. states               The United States                                             I don't see data from europe. how can I extract data for one country?

Comment: Did you read the section of https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html on "Specific geospatial data sources of interest "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily extract some data from the package `rworldmap`. Here is some code to illustrate:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(rworldmap)
# Get the world map
worldMap <- getMap()

# Member States of the European Union
europeanUnion <- c("Austria","Belgium","Bulgaria","Croatia","Cyprus",
                   "Czech Rep.","Denmark","Estonia","Finland","France",
                   "Germany","Greece","Hungary","Ireland","Italy","Latvia",
                   "Lithuania","Luxembourg","Malta","Netherlands","Poland",
                   "Portugal","Romania","Slovakia","Slovenia","Spain",
                   "Sweden","United Kingdom")
# Select only the index of states member of the E.U.
indEU <- which(worldMap$NAME%in%europeanUnion)

# Extract longitude and latitude border's coordinates of members states of E.U. 
europeCoords <- lapply(indEU, function(i){
  df <- data.frame(worldMap@polygons[[i]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords)
  df$region =as.character(worldMap$NAME[i])
  colnames(df) <- list("long", "lat", "region")
  return(df)
})

europeCoords <- do.call("rbind", europeCoords)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `giscoR` for map political borders and `eurostat` for regional statistics. Both are based on the open data provided by Eurostat.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments above, that the Spatial Data Analysis Task View cited above is a very good starting point. In addition to the answers above, you might consider reviewing [GADMTools](https://github.com/IamKDO/GADMTools), which is an R package to manipulate vector adminstrative boundaries from [GADM](https://gadm.org/).

With respect to GADM, under the [Data download](https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html) section you can download Rds files (sp/sf formats) as well as Geopackages and ESRI Shapefiles.